# How to update child grid checkboxes onRowSelected event in ag grid

Tags: c#, reactjs, ag-grid

Is it possible to update child grid checkboxes status on parent row checkbox selection in ag-grid.

Am using ag-grid with masterDetail is true. (Not group)

```
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/master-detail-grids/
```

OnRowSelected event am getting current row data and nested grid data, but I want to update checkbox status of nested grid

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Basically, we need to find the selected row's detail grid and select its all children programmatically*

The code which matters for this question

```
onRowSelected: (params) => {
  console.log('params', params) // params has an index value of the selected row here

  // we iterate over the nodes to find the selected row and then its detail rows
  params.api.forEachNode(function (record, index) {
    if (record.rowIndex == params.rowIndex) {
      console.log(record.detailNode.id) // this is the id of the detail grid of the selected row

      // we set all rows selected for the detail grid
      gridOptions.api.getDetailGridInfo(record.detailNode.id).api
        .forEachNode((dNode) => dNode.setSelected(true))
    }
  })
}
```

I have got a Plunker ready for you

https://plnkr.co/plunk/WK8rf6gtGucBdQiN